# ERROR.diagnostics has wrong file/line number, what gives?

Tags: coldfusion

In my error template, I'm sending myself an email, on exception.  Like we do.  Using #ERROR.diagnostics# I got a message like:

```
Element SOMEVAR is undefined in URL. 
The error occurred on line 1.
```

The problem is, this error did not occur on line #1 of the file that it reported, in #ERROR.template# (mainfile.cfm)  The error occured in an included file, from mainfile.cfm.  Also, the error was not on line 1, but line 2.

How can I get a more accurate error message?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: coldfusion Version 11

Comment: When I email error information, I include dumps of all relevant scopes.  If it's in the onError method of Application.cfc, as a minimum, I include `Arguments.Exception`.